# Create class Color in RGB in C#

Tags: c#

I tried to create class Color in RGB in C#, values of colors (red, green, blue) must be inside range [0,1].
It's my code

```
public class ColorRGB
    {
        private ColorRGB(double _red, double _green, double _blue)
        {
            Red = _red;
            Green = _green;
            Blue = _blue;
        }

        public static ColorRGB ColorRGB_RGBModel(double _red, double _green, double _blue)
        {
            return new ColorRGB(_red, _green, _blue);
        }

        public static ColorRGB ColorRGB_CMYModel(double _cyan, double _magenta, double _yellow)
        {
            var _red = 1 - _cyan;
            var _green = 1 - _magenta;
            var _blue = 1 - _yellow;
            return new ColorRGB(_red, _green, _blue);
        }

        public ColorRGB AddRGB(ColorRGB _secondColor)
        {
            return ColorRGB_RGBModel(this.Red + _secondColor.Red, this.Green + _secondColor.Green, this.Blue + _secondColor.Blue);
        }

        public ColorRGB SubtractRGB(ColorRGB _secondColor)
        {
            return ColorRGB_RGBModel(this.Red - _secondColor.Red, this.Green - _secondColor.Green, this.Blue - _secondColor.Blue);
        }

        public double Red {
            get { return red; }
            private set { red = red < 0 ? 0 : (red > 1 ? 1 : value); }
        }
        public double Green
        {
            get { return green; }
            private set { green = green < 0 ? 0 : (green > 1 ? 1 : value); }
        }
        public double Blue
        {
            get { return blue; }
            private set { blue = blue < 0 ? 0 : (blue > 1 ? 1 : value); }
        }
        public double Cyan
        {
            get { return cyan; }
            private set { cyan = cyan < 0 ? 0 : (cyan > 1 ? 1 : value); }
        }
        public double Magenta
        {
            get { return magenta; }
            private set { magenta = magenta < 0 ? 0 : (magenta > 1 ? 1 : value); }
        }
        public double Yellow
        {
            get { return yellow; }
            private set { yellow = yellow < 0 ? 0 : (yellow > 1 ? 1 : value); }
        }

        private double red;
        private double green;
        private double blue;
        private double cyan;
        private double magenta;
        private double yellow;
    }
}
```

but when I tried to create an instance of this class and tried to set values of colors (red, greed, blue) out of range [0, 1], my checkings `red = red < 0 ? 0 : (red > 1 ? 1 : value);` and others didn't work.
Can someone explain me why it happens and how to fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `value` more and `red` less:

```
public double Red {
    get { return red; }
    private set { red = value < 0 ? 0 : (value > 1 ? 1 : value); }
}
```

At the moment, you're checking the *current* value of the local variable, rather than the value that the user is trying to set. (Similarly, for all of the other `set` methods - you're checking the local variable, which contains the old value that's about to be replaced - not the `value` parameter)

---

I'm also unsure why you have CMY properties/variables when they're ignored by your constructor, and never relate to the RGB values - but maybe that's code that you're yet to write.

---

As suggested to Izzy, you could add a function to your method:

```
private static double Bound(double value) {
   return value < 0 ? 0 : (value > 1 ? 1 : value);
}
```

And then re-write your setters as:

```
private set { red = Bound(value); }
```

Which should make you code look cleaner

Comment: I was going to suggest factorising the bounds checking into it's own function to make testing easier.. but this is the answer :)

Comment: I created and used method Bound, and it works, but reSharped suggested  me to make this method `static`. Why?

Comment: @Heidel - because the method, by itself, doesn't access any of the state (such as local variables) of the class - it just operates on the parameter that it receives - so it doesn't need to be a member function.